# Generalized Gronwall inequality for singular differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Consider a differential inequality of the form
$$
  y'(t) \leq K(t)y(t) + f(t), \: y(0) = a < \infty, \; t\in(0,1]
$$
Here $K(t)>0$ is decreasing function of $t$ such that
$$
  K(t) \leq C\frac{\vert\ln t\vert}{t}, C>0.
$$

Is there a generalization of Gronwall inequality to study this kind problems?

Answer (score 1):

Let $t_0\in (0,1]$ and set $\kappa (t)=\int_{t_0}^tK(u)\,\mathrm d u$, $t\geq t_0$. Then, for all $t\geq t_0$,

\begin{align*}
y'(t)\leq K(t)y(t)+f(t)&\iff y'(t)e^{-\kappa (t)}-K(t)y(t)e^{-\kappa (t)}\leq f(t)e^{-\kappa (t)}\\
&\iff y(t)e^{-\kappa (t)}\leq y(t_0) +\int_{t_0}^t f(u)e^{-\kappa (u)\,\mathrm d u}\\
&\iff y(t)\leq e^{\kappa (t)}y(t_0)+e^{\kappa (t)}\int_{t_0}^tf(u)e^{-\kappa (u)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: $\kappa(t)$ may not be bounded.

Comment: @RahulRajuPattar: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to this condition. Does something like that would works (see my edit) ? If not, I'll erase my answer.